# can not open database on localnetworks

Tags: c#, sql-server, networking

I write a win app,and i create my database on the server by codes.now every client on local network can't login to my database and this error occured

```
:"cannot open database "test" requested by the login.the login failed for user "farzane".
```

the connectionstring for to make my database is:

```
ConnectionString=@"Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False";
```

and it's my connection string for open my database:

```
ConnectionString=@"Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False";
```

how can give permission for logining to my database to any client with codes???
thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check two things here:

1. Ensure that your SQL Express install allows remote connections. (Simple to check using SQL Server Studio Manager).
2. You are using trusted authentication in your connection string.  You have to explicitly give users on your domain access on the database.  You will have to this in SQL Server.

Comment: how can i give access to any users in SQL Server??i coulden't with code set this access??

Comment: Yes you can programmaticly add it by using `CREATE LOGIN` see   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx

Answer (score 0):

are you using a domain for the network ?
if yes then make sure that the user name has access to the SQL server

if you're using a workgroup then it won't work... just create a user on the sql server and use the sql server auth at the server and connection string

Comment: yes i use domain for the network,how can i understand that the username has access to the SQL server??/

Answer (score 0):

Points i concluded:

1. First of all the users who are going to create the database , must be authorized to use master database. So ask your admin to allow permission to farzanne.
2. If you(farzanne) are admin, set farzanne to create databases permission to true. Or the other users that might create dbs. Also, if you allow all users then it will be difficult to handle, your application, so be alert.
3. What is the need of the dynamically createing database from application. Is this a part of setup or deployment or you are creating an isolated space that is different user different database.

Comment: @AmRan:every user in domain at first time make his database with different name on the server,now how can give permission to them to access to the database that they created with cods??

Comment: @AmRan:i mean they can create their database but they can't access to them.

Comment: @Farzanne. Why so? Why do'nt you are handling all users in a single database. Take a scenario if there are 50 users, then u must need 50 separate database. What if the admin wants to print reports on the user basis.. Rethink... If its end client requirement, then no issues, but try to agree him , not to use such scenario, as it will become mamoth in maintanence.

Comment: @AmRan:for my app we should do this scenario.

Comment: @AmRan:when i right clicked on my database that created and in Permission add guest,then every user in domain have access to my database but how can do it with code??

Comment: @Farzanne - it would be a great help, if you elaborate your original scenario. What are your requirements and what is your approach? Then we can suggest you the solution.